# Start and end date on the same line. Date Picker Range Python Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm using Date Picker Range from dash components in python.
However, in the documentation it has the start date and end
date on the same line, but when I do it it is on two lines.
Does anyone know how to adjust this?

in my code

[image]

in the documentation

[image]

thanks in advance!!!

My code:

```py
from dash import dcc
from datetime import date
import dash
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
    
    
app = dash.Dash(__name__, title = 'Testando format', external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.LITERA])
    
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.P('try dash Date Picker Range'),
            dcc.DatePickerRange(
                            end_date=date(2017, 6, 21),
                            display_format='MMMM Y, DD',
                            start_date_placeholder_text='MMMM Y, DD'
                        )
        ], md = 12)
    ])
], fluid = True)
    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

Comment: I checked it in my environment (`jupyterLab`) and it is displayed in one line as per the official sample. The versions used are `dash` 2.2.0 and `dash_bootstrap_components` 1.03. Which version are you using?